# How to add money to a Paypal sandbox account, after it has been created?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I specified an amount that was too low for my testing needs, when creating a personal paypal sandbox account. Is there any way to add money to an account, after it has been created?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you need actual funds in that account you could use Send Money from another sandbox account and pay the account you want to fund.

You really don't need funds in the account to test payments, though.  As long as the account is verified and confirmed it'll fall to "Instant Transfer" and you won't have any problems sending payments using that account.

Comment: Ahh, thanks Andrew. I didn't want to wait until the account went negative and suddenly have all my tests fail. So an account with negative funds would still allow for successful payments?

Comment: Not negative funds, no.  But $0 balance, yes, as long as you have the bank and credit card setup.

Comment: They've changed this. A merchant sandbox account with $0 will fail to send payments and payouts through the API's.

Comment: @IncredibleHat, not if the sandbox buyer account you are using has a credit card attached to it, which it would if you have the credit card added like I said originally.

Answer (score 8):

1. Login using your developer PayPal account https://developer.paypal.com/
2. Go to 'My Account' on the top right section of the page.
3. Go to Accounts under Sandbox.
4. See your sandbox account and click on the Clone link.
5. Fill the details and mention the amount you want to have and click on Create.

This is helpful in case if the amount in the existing sandbox account is exhausted.

Comment: this is the CORRECT answer

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps:-

1. Go to https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/
2. Click on the email address used for the account (email address)
3. Now two option you will get --> Profile and notification (just below that email you clicked)
4. Choose profile then a popup will come
5. Now choose funding tab in popups.
6. Now at the bottom choose edit button and edit the balance and save.

That's it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't go to sandbox, go to developer.paypal.com
Log in with your real paypal account (not sandbox).
Go to Sandbox - > Accounts on the left.
Click in the button "Create account"
You will be able to add any amount you want.

Answer (score 1):

Why not duplicate the sandbox account (to have another name), then delete the orginal, then duplicate the new created one with your original name ?
This seems to work with buyer account, seller are usually used with api key

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new account inside your Paypal developer account and simply enter the number how much you want in your account.

Comment: The question states after an account has been created

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to [PayPal Dev portal](https://developer.paypal.com/) with your actual Paypal account credentials
2. Navigate to this path - Testing tools > Sandbox accounts
3. Select your account from the list
4. Scroll down until you see PayPal balance or the below page

[image]

5. Edit the PayPal balance amount as your want

It will reflect the money to your PayPal Sandbox account!